# Comparing solutions of logistic equation and Gompertz equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

Considering the Gompertz equation, $\frac{dN}{dt}=r_oe^{-\alpha t}N$, and the logistic growth equation, $\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-\frac{N}{k})$. How is the carrying capacity from Gompertz equation differ from that of the logistic growth? What about the inflection point?

I'm having coding problems uploading the solution curves for both equations, but this link contains a good sample of what it should look like, [Logistic and Gompertz solution curve](https://www.chebfun.org/examples/applics/Gompertz.html)

After finding solutions for both, I obtain for the Gompertz, $N(t)=N_0\exp(\frac{r_0}{\alpha}[1-e^{-\alpha t}])$, and for logistic growth, $N(t)=\frac{k}{1+(\frac{k}{N_0}-1)e^{-rt}}$. So taking the limit we obtain the carrying for capacity for Gompertz, $N^*=N_0e^{\frac{r_0}{\alpha}}$, and for logistic growth it is obviously, $N^*=k$. From here I am confused as to how to proceed in showing how they differ or not.

For the inflection point, we have, $N=\frac{k}{2}$, for logistic growth, and, $N=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ for the Gompertz, but yet again I'm not sure how to compare the two to see how they differ.

The reason for all the madness should yield the derivation of the new form of the Gompertz equation, $\frac{dN}{dt}=\alpha N\ln(\frac{k}{N})$.

Comment: Mathematical objects can differ in many ways -- clearly they are different equations and curves, so what aspects are you trying to compare?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how they obtained the new derivation for the Gompertz, obviously there is some relationship from observing the expected result

Comment: I digress from my comment, I misunderstood the question. It's a lot simpler than I thought